# PHP Codeigniter - Fill select with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Im trying to fill a select with elements from a database using Ajax but it wont work.
If have pinned down the problem to the javascript function but I don't seem to find the problem myself.

What am I missing here? :/

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {           
        $(function()
        { 
            $.ajax(
            {
                url:"<?php echo site_url("c_admin/ajaxCategorie");?>",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(msg)
                {                           
                    var jsonMsg = $.parseJSON(msg);
                    var count = Object.keys(jsonMsg).length;
                    for(var x = 0; x < count; x++)
                    {   
                        $("#categorieSelect").apend($("<option></option>").val(jsonMsg[x].CategorieID).html(jsonMsg[x].CategorieNaam));             
                    }
                }
            });       
        });     
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you made a simple typo;

```
       $("#categorieSelect").apend($("<option></option>").val(jsonMsg[x].CategorieID).html(jsonMsg[x].CategorieNaam));
```

Change apend to append.
Your code should be ok !